# jQuery UI autocomplete wait for search event to complete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a textbox bound to jQuery UI's autocomplete. When the user selects an option from the autocomplete dropdown, JSON data is used to populate a form with user details from a remote source.

I have a reset button with the following function bound to it:

```
$('#btn_reset').on('click', function() {
    $('#txt_name').autocomplete('search');
    $('.ui-menu-item').children().eq(0).click();
    return false;
});
```

This works with a small amount of local data as `search` is completed before `click()` is called, however with a large amount of external data, the `search` does not complete in time, thus giving me an `'item' is null or not an object` error.

How can I get jQuery to wait until `search` is completed before calling `click()`?

Here is a working fiddle using a local data source: http://jsfiddle.net/3KTtT/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to bind a function to the `open` event of autocomplete to check for a boolean variable to determine whether or not the form was being reset.

```
var reset = false;
$(function() {    
    $('#txt_name').autocomplete({
        source: [{"label":"john smith","address":"19 Tree Lane"}],
        delay: 0,
        autoFocus: true,
        open: function() {
            if(reset){
                $('.ui-menu-item').children().eq(0).click();
                reset = false;
            }
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#txt_address').val(ui.item.address);
        }

    });

    $('#btn_reset').on('click', function() {
        reset = true;
        $('#txt_name').autocomplete('search');
        return false;
    });

});
```

See here for fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RVnkz/2/

Comment: Cool stuff man. Glad you got it sorted. Does it work well with remote data now?

Comment: Yeah working perfectly :) was trying to find a basic remote JSON data source to post my original fiddle with but to no avail...
Thanks again for the help btw

Answer (score 0):

I've altered your example to include a delay loop where it checks if there is a value and then I called your click event. Should put you on the right track:

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jjay225/3KTtT/18/)

If you look at the below code I've got greater than 0 just so you can test the code but it should be less than 1.

```
  $('#btn_reset').on('click', function() {
    $('#txt_name').autocomplete('search');
    if($('#txt_name').val().length>0) //THIS LINE
    {
      CheckValue();
   } 
    else
    {                      
    $('.ui-menu-item').children().eq(0).click();
    return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: `CheckValue` only seems to add a one off delay of 1500 before `click()` is fired :(

Comment: yes thats right because it finds that there is a value present for "txt_name". If it doesn't you see CheckValue() is called again if "loaded" is not equal to 1. Check this altered [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjay225/3KTtT/20/) - I've gone and set "loaded" equal to 0 and added a console.log to show you how many times its called.

Comment: thank you for the help with this but i've just figured out a completely different way that doesn't have a delay between the autocomplete opening and the `click()`. I'll post it as an answer in a second